# ubuntu 14.04 /etc/init.d/ vs /etc/init/ start service at startup

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

From what I understood, the /etc/init.d directory contains the scripts executed by init at boot time.
Is that only for Debian or for Ubuntu 14.04 as well?

I am wondering because I have several scripts in the init.d directory but they do not seem to be run when the server starts.
Is there a log to check?

For example, when I installed supervisor (`apt-get install supervisor`), it created an init script in `/etc/init.d/supervisor` which is supposed to start it but when I start my server, supervisor does not run.
I have some other examples so it does not seem to be related to the supervisor script only.

Also, what is the difference between `/etc/init.d` and `etc/init` ? I am confused.

Thanks

Comment: Did you found out how to autostart supervisor?

Comment: There's a very good more accurate/indepth answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5039/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-init-and-etc-init-d

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The scripts in `/etc/init.d/` are scripts that control services. Controlling means that they take care of starting, stopping and similar actions.

They are *not* automatically executed at startup. Instead, you must assign scripts to [*runlevels*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel), which is done with the `update-rc.d` command on Debian-based systems (which Ubuntu is).

For example, to add your supervisor service to all default runlevels, you would execute

```
sudo update-rc.d supervisor defaults
```

Also, you're asking for the difference between `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/init`:

- `/etc/init.d` contains the service scripts,
- `/etc/init` contains configuration for these scripts (descriptions. dependencies, post-/pre-actions). However IIRC, `/etc/init` is specific to [SysV init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style).

Comment: oh ok, I misunderstood the purpose of the init scripts then. When I read the supervisor documentation, it sounded like using a init script would make supervisord run automatically on startup: http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisord-automatically-on-startup
I  tried the ```sudo update-rc.d``` command but I get this message ```System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/supervisor already exist.```. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Also, I made more research and I found that looking at ```service --status-all```, I can see the services that are started at OS boot (the ones with a "+" sign in front of them) and supervisor is not since it has a "-" sign. :/

Comment: Ok, that's a bit weird. Could you do the following: Create a new post (and maybe better on [Unix/Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)) describe that phenomenon there. Because it would be easier to discuss this in a new post, and it's likely to attract more readers.

Comment: This answer seems like misinformation to me.  isn't `/etc/init` part of upstart and `/etc/init.d/` the old Sys V Init?

Comment: It is true that `/etc/init` was introduced by Upstart, while `/etc/init.d` goes back to SysV. However, my point was that `/etc/init.d` contains scripts to be executed, while `/etc/init` contains configuration. But, upstart is dead anyway, and systemd introduces `/etc/systemd`. Note that `/etc/init` as well as `/etc/init.d` still exist on current Ubuntus (15.04 here), but I guess these are just transitional files installed by packages that support all three init systems.